# Issue with persisting data using de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

Tags: mongodb, embedded, embedded-database

I'm having trouble with persisting data using de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo. I've followed the documentation and examples I found online, but when I shut down my application, the data disappears.

Here's the code I'm using to start the embedded MongoDB server:

```
    Mongod mongod = new Mongod() {
        @Override
        public Transition<PersistentDir> persistentBaseDir() {
            return Start.to(PersistentDir.class)
                .providedBy(PersistentDir.inUserHome(".embeddedMongodbCustomPath")
                .mapToUncheckedException(RuntimeException::new));
        }
    };
    
    TransitionWalker.ReachedState<RunningMongodProcess> running = Mongod.builder()
        .net(Start.to(Net.class)
        .initializedWith(Net.defaults().withPort(37017)))
        .persistentBaseDir(mongod.persistentBaseDir())
        .build()
        .start(Version.V6_0_1);
```

I'm using the MongoClient class to connect to the embedded MongoDB server:

```
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                        MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), 

    CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new AccountCodec())
                    );
                    MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                            .writeConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALED).build();
        
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost:37017", options);
```

Until here, I'm not getting any exceptions.

And here's the code I'm using to insert data:

```
    Document accounts = new Document();
    List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    Account account1 = new Account("john@gmail.com", "sdfhsidf");
    Account account2 = new Account("duck@gmail.com", "ouihod");
    accountList.add(account1);
    accountList.add(account2);
    
    db.getCollection("accounts").insertOne(accounts.append("account", accountList));
```

But after insert I get the following exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled' on server localhost:37017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
```

and the data doesn't persist after I shut down my application.
Perhaps am I not configuring MongoDB Embedded Server to use the persistence of data? In my filesystem, as shown in the code above I note that the application created the folder and some files inside it.

Can anyone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.